# Is there a way in Objective-C to set a property value without directly invoking the setter?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way in Objective-C to set a property value of a class instance X without directly invoking the setter, but just somehow specifying the property name ?

I have a NSDictionary in which the keys are the property names and the values are the values to assign.

Now I just would like to iterate my NSDictionary and set the property of the instance X by just specifying the key.

I hope it is clear...
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using *Key Value Coding*. Just use the `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:` methods to set and get properties. Behind the scenes those will use the setters if available, but they also can access ivars directly, if there are no accessors.